# Remove Padding ImageButton

Tags: android

[image: this is my button]

I’m using ImageButton and I can’t remove a padding or space between my image and the border of the button. How can I achieve this?

this is my layout

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton"
 style="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
 android:layout_width="103dp"
 android:layout_height="110dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:paddingBottom="-15dp"
 android:paddingTop="30dp"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why you don't use an _ImageView_ with a _RelativeLayout_ as parent? This way you can set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your _ImageView_ and everything "should" work fine.

Comment: can you post a complete xml(i.e.) at least from this ImageButton Parent?

Comment: Thank you very much! this was my solution:

`android:paddingBottom="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much! this was my solution:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton"
style="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:layout_width="103dp"
android:layout_height="110dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 />
```

I set padding bottom to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this! may work for you

```
android:scaleType="centercrop"
```